# How to re-run Keycloak JavaScript adapter check-sso

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-js, keycloak-javascript

I'm using [Keycloak JavaScript adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_javascript_adapter) in my single page web app. I execute

```
adapter = new Keycloak({
  url: ENV.APP.KEYCLOAK_URL,
  realm: ENV.APP.KEYCLOAK_REALM,
  clientId: ENV.APP.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
});

const keycloak_window = window.open(
  // Documentation at https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#methods
  adapter.createLoginUrl(),
  "_blank",
  "popup=true,width=300,height=300",
);
```

This starts Keycloak JavaScript adapter and  open a new window for the user to provide their credentials. This works as expected.

I have more code to update the single page web app when the authentication is complete but it is missing a way to re-run Keycloak JavaScript adapter's `check-sso`. How can I re-run the `check-sso`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Keycloak JS adapter in this manner, if you want to sign in a user you will have to call the `.login()` method, which will redirect the user to Keycloak. Signing in through a separate window is not supported.

Your code should look roughly like this:

```js
const keycloak = new Keycloak({
  url: ENV.APP.KEYCLOAK_URL,
  realm: ENV.APP.KEYCLOAK_REALM,
  clientId: ENV.APP.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
});

const authenticated = await keycloak.init({
  onLoad: 'check-sso',
});

if (!authenticated) {
  await keycloak.login();
}
```

I recommend that you read the [Keycloak JS documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_javascript_adapter), it should give you a good idea of how things should work.